Linked Stylesheets in Angular: Understanding Inline Inconsistencies
I ran into a problem with how Angular handles styles: With some linked stylesheets, Angular makes them inline on build, but with other linked stylesheets it doesn't. In neither case are any of these linked styles used. Any ideas on why this might be happening?
I'm using Angular v18.1.2 and Node v22.5.1.
Here's an example: In this example I link two different stylesheets, neither of which are used in the application, yet one gets put inline on build and the other does not:
Step #1 -- I create a new Angular project:
$ npx -p @angular/cli@18.1.2 ng new angularStylesIssue --style=css --routing=false --ssr=false

$ cd angularStylesIssue

Step #2 -- I insert a link to a stylesheet before the close of the head block in my HTML code:
$ sed -i '/<\/head>/i <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />' .\src\index.html

Step #3 -- I build the application:
$ npm run build

Step #4 -- I observe that styles for my linked stylesheet are not inserted inline:
$ cat .\dist\angular-styles-issue\browser\index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularStylesIssue</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-5INURTSO.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-EZFZMKPF.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>

Step #5 -- If I had used a different stylesheet, it would have been added inline without any issues, unlike the previous one that failed to do so. For example:
$ git checkout .

$ sed -i '/<\/head>/i <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />' .\src\index.html

$ npm run build

$ cat .\dist\angular-styles-issue\browser\index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container>
<head><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularStylesIssue</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<style>@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v142/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;-webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga';-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-5INURTSO.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="polyfills-SCHOHYNV.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-EZFZMKPF.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>

